# Distinguish between variables and constant in sympy symbolic expression

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, codegen

I am taking from user a symbolic expression as input and then differentiating it wrt to variables and then making a matrix consisting of the expression and differentiated expression. Then passed this through codegen to generate a c file.

But I want the code to consider some specific symbols as variable and other as constant. How to do so?

Comment: Please put together a minimum working example to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.